SQLalchemy and Langchain: How to select a specific table?
I am new to data engineering and I'm trying to use the sql agent in Langchain but I cannot seem to ingest the sql table correctly. Basically, I connect to the server, but I need to execute something to get the data as there are multiple tables. Although I can access the data by executing a query, I cannot use this in the function since after querying it's a list.
How can I make sure this works?
This is what I tried before and which does not work:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine_azure = create_engine(conn_str,echo=True)
engine_azure.execute("SELECT * FROM META.Curves").fetchall() 
db = SQLDatabase(engine_azure)   

but basically there is no data in the db variable. I have about 4 tables in my server.
